# Attribute on property not found

Tags: c#, reflection

```
[MyAttribute("x")]
public string Z{get;set;}

[MyAttribute("x")]
public void Y()
{

}
```

It finds the attr on the method just fine, but the one on the property isn't recognized.

```
public static bool HasAttribute(this MethodInfo m, Type attrType)
{
    return Attribute.IsDefined(m, attrType);
}
```

I looked at the object during debugging and at the method it correctly lists the Attribute at CustomAttributes, but the one on the property is empty... can anyone explain?

Comment: Seems odd. Tried closing your editor and reopening it? Rebooting?

Comment: How is `MyAttribute` defined?

Comment: Add the declaration of MyAttribute? Or at least the AttributeUsage part.

Comment: Also, how are you calling this in the property case? Passing in the get or set method won't carry over the attribute declaration...I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the attribute on the property, not on the property accessors. To provide the attribute on the getter, you would use this syntax (I included all 3 possible locations, you can choose to add the attribute on any combination depending on its applicability).

```
[MyAttribute("on PropertyInfo")]
public string Z
{
    [MyAttribute("on getter MethodInfo")] get;
    [MyAttribute("on setter MethodInfo")] set;
}
```

Comment: Most likely this, kinda what I was alluding to in comments

Comment: Yeah nów it works.. can't believe I wasted so much time on this one. Thanks much! Also, is there any way to get to the propertyinfo's attribute via the methodinfo object? Let me rephrase that; what's the most efficient way to do that? Because I have no doubt it's possible one way or another.

Comment: For each `PropertyInfo` in the type, check to see if the `GetGetAccessor` or `GetSetAccessor` equals the `MethodInfo` you have